# Add calculated column to table ssms (sql query)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, calculated-columns, alter-table

Im trying to add and save a new calculated column to the table energy, using the following sql query:

```
ALTER TABLE energy
  ADD energie_active_1 float

SELECT *,
       energie_active - LAG(energie_active, 1, energie_active)
                          OVER (
                            PARTITION BY DESIGNATION
                            ORDER BY TS)
FROM   energy
```

But i get the column energie_active_1 empty and a new column without name with the calculated values (as shwon in the image)
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkKHb.png)

I dont use sql queries a lot, so any help or advice would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your sql is 1) creating a column called energie_active_1 with a datatype as float.  then 2) running a completely separate statement which is a query.

In other words, you created a column, but not a calculated column. Then you ran a normal query.

Comment: I'm not really sure that computed columns can use lag functions - dunno. You can certainly just use your query and not create a calculated column....

Comment: Rather than add the column to the table, just alias the column in the query as `energie_active_1`. One cannot use windowing functions in a computed column expression.

Comment: Cannot define a data type for a table calculated field. Try: `energie_active_1 AS SELECT ...`. But as already noted, some functions cannot be used in table calculated field. Just build a query with the calc.

Comment: Ok i see whats wrong now, but i need to have this calculated column in the table, cause its used by a Power bi dashboard to show the energie_active_1; and i cant do these calculations on Power bi "i get not enough memory" cause table contains a lot of rows.

Comment: If you need to refer to this column regularly use a *view*.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table TABLE_NAME
add [column_name] as (**COLUMN-SQL**)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.
So this is what i have came with, not sure if its the correct way to do it. But its working for me :)

```
INSERT INTO energy ( energy.TS
     , energy.DESIGNATION 
     , energy.energie_active,
     energy.energie_reactive,
     energie_active_1 ) (SELECT energy.TS
     , energy.DESIGNATION 
     , energy.energie_active,
     energy.energie_reactive,energy.energie_active-LAG(energy.energie_active, 1, energy.energie_active) OVER (PARTITION BY energy.DESIGNATION ORDER BY energy.TS)FROM energy)
```

Now i get the new column in the same table.

Comment: If it works for you then that's all that matters but this is not what you asked for - what happens if any existing row has `energie_active` column updated? PS you can remove the repeated table name from the insert and select, it's not needed.